# Contact form reply to sender

Tags: php, email, contact-form

So I've completed a contact form made in PHP. After testing it sends emails, but in the email header it is not capturing the sender's name or email address. It shows up as sh-908129268@eu.hosting-webspace.io

Is there a way to correct that? I need to be able to respond to emails.

The inputs are as follows:

```
<form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<input class="input is-small" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Text input" value="<?= $name ?>" >
<p class="help is-danger"><?= $name_error ?></p>

<input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?= $email?>">
<p class="help is-danger"><?= $email_error?></p>

// back-end file

$sendTo = 'test@email.com';
        $subject = 'Business Enquiry';
        $headers = "";

        $headers .= "Sent From: ".$name. "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply To: ".$email. "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Message: ".$message. "\r\n";

        if (mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

            $success = "Thank you for your message, I will reply as soon as I can.";
            $name = $email = $message = ''; // resets all fields
        }
```

Comment: sometimes hosts (mostly free ones) don't allow you to change the from address, additionally, your code is open so some nasties like XSS and email header injection

Comment: It's currently on a paid package with a host. If the code is that vulnerable is there a way to better secure it?

Comment: That being said, I contacted the host for advice and they insisted it's something to do with the way the form is coded

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pick the names of the headers freely, you have to adhere to the standard ([RFC 5322 Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)).

Your header "*Sent From*" should be just `From`, your header "*Reply To*" should be `Reply-To` and your header "Message" shouldn't be in the headers at all - you already pass the message as such into the mail function.

Answer (score 0):

All fixed now, thanks. All I needed was to specify one header ,

$headers = "From: ".$email;

So it's just $subject and $headers